# Загрузка 64-битной dll из 32-битной dll

Tags: c++, dll, com, процесс, ipc

Какой существует наилучший способ загрузить **64-битную** динамическую библиотеку из **32-битной**? Функция **LoadLibrary()** в данном случае не поможет, так как битность разная.

Видел много подобных вопросов, где пишут, что нужно создать отдельный процесс, в котором подгрузить **dll**-ку и средствами **IPC (Inter-Process Communication)** взаимодействовать с ним, однако нигде нет примеров. Единственный ли это способ и действительно ли он лучший? В ответе прошу приводить пример программного кода на языке **C++**.

**P.S.:**

Есть вот такая статья, но там случай ровно наоборот: [Accessing 32-bit DLLs from 64-bit code](https://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/) и без примеров.

В этой статье пишут, что можно обойтись без **COM** и **IPC**, используя функцию **LoadLibraryEx()**: [Lesson 2. Support of 32-bit applications in the 64-bit Windows environment](http://www.viva64.com/en/l/full/).

> It is impossible to load a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit process and
>   execute its code. It is impossible due to the design of 64-bit
>   systems. It is impossible fundamentally. And no tricks and
>   undocumented means will help you. To do this you will have to load and
>   initialize WoW64, not to speak of the kernel structures. Actually, it
>   means that a 64-bit process must be made 32-bit "on the fly". This
>   topic is described more thoroughly in the post "Why can't you thunk
>   between 32-bit and 64-bit Windows?". The only thing we can recommend
>   is to create a surrogate process and work with it through the COM
>   technology. You may read about it in the article "Accessing 32-bit
>   DLLs from 64-bit code".
>
> But it is quite easy to load resources from a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit
>   process. You may do it specifying the flag **LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE**
>   when calling **LoadLibraryEx**.

Однако, в описании функции отсюда: [Функция LoadLibraryEx](http://www.vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/DLL/fn_loadlibraryex.htm) говорится, что:

> LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE. Если это значение используется, система
>   преобразует и проецирует данные файла в виртуальное адресное
>   пространство вызывающего процесса, так, как если бы он был файлом
>   данных. Ничего не делается, чтобы исполнить код или подготовиться к
>   исполнению отображаемого файла. Поэтому, Вы не можете вызывать функции
>   подобно GetModuleHandle или GetProcAddress для этой DLL. Используйте
>   этот флажок тогда, когда  хотите загрузить DLL только для того, чтобы
>   извлечь сообщения или ресурсы из нее.

Значит, такой вариант не подойдёт.

Comment: Всмысле перекомпилировать как 64-битную?

Comment: @gil9red, ничего перекомпилировать не нужно. Нужно выплонить что-то наподобие **LoadLibrary()** из 32-битной dll-ки. А библиотека, которую хочется загрузить 64-битная.

Comment: @neo указанный пример позволяет использовать ресурсы, но ни как уж не функции. Да и в окружении 64 бита, а не 32. Читайте ж внимательно.

Comment: @Евгений Борисов, а вы внимательно прочитали, что я написал? Перечитайте ещё раз.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это единственный способ. Как 64-битная DLL-ка сможет работать в 32-битном процессе? Как вы сможете туда передать, например, указатель?

Comment: @neo, крайне внимательно посмотрите на пример. but it is easy to load **resources**

Comment: @VladD, если так, то необходим пример работы с COM в контексте задачи, заявленной в вопросе, или хотя бы примерный алгоритм действий.

Comment: @Евгений Борисов, ваше замечание никоим образом не помогает решить задачу, заявленную в вопросе.

Comment: @neo. Как сказать-то. Оно отмечает, что простой пример, который Вы нашли не решает проблему даже в направлении 64-32. Лишь IPC взаимодействие вам в помощь. Лёгких путей не будет.

Comment: @neo: Ну, COM по большому счёту не обязателен, вам нужен любой способ связать между собой код в разных процессах. На COM это делать удобно, но можно и на любом IPC. То есть возьмите любой хэлловорлд на COM, он подойдёт (только вам нужен по идее outproc-сервер). // Но да, примера на C++ в моём комментарии нет. Может, кто-то напишет.

Comment: @Евгений Борисов, я сам в вопросе написал, что этот способ **НЕ ПОДХОДИТ**. Зачем дублировать?

Answer (score 3):

- В вопросе совершенно верно замечено, что нет никакого способа выполнить код `x64` библиотеки из `32` битного процесса.
- Также совершенно верно то, что самый простой способ - это запустить или использовать другой `64` битный процесс, загрузив библиотеку в него. Для этого потребуется [межпроцессное взаимодействие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5), т.е. передача данных от одного процесса к другому.
- Вопрос передачи данных - является отдельным вопросом и сильно зависит от контекста задачи, описания которого здесь нет. В самом простом случае данные в поток назначения можно передать из командной строки, а вернуть `int` в качестве возвращаемого значения `DllMain`, либо записать в файл результат. В более сложных случаях можно использовать [именованные трубы](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=named+pipe), [очереди сообщений](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows+messages), даже можно запустить процесс на другом компьютере и обмениваться через сеть.

Если нужен совет по межпроцессному взаимодействию, то рекомендую задать вопрос с конкретными требованиями.